# Use of Callout changes plot fonts and lines

Tags: plotting, labeling

When I use `Callout` to place a label above the bars on a `BarChart` a number of other things happen to the graph unexpectedly. The fonts and lines appear to be a different weight. The y-axis of the graph also changes even though the `Callout` would easily fit without altering the axis.

Here is a minimal example:

`BarChart[{10}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Title",  FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, 20}]`

produces

[image]

`BarChart[{10}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Title",  FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, 20},  LabelingFunction -> (Callout[#] &)]`

produces

[image]

I was worried that I was misunderstanding `LabelingFunction` so did an alternative version without that. But it gives the same result

`BarChart[{Callout[10, "10"]}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Title",  FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, 20}]`

produces

[image]

I think I am obviously misunderstanding something. I can semi understand altering the y-axis range. But not in my example where it seems not to be needed. I am more puzzled by the style changes.

I assume this is expected behaviour? Is there any way to stop `Callout` doing this, or get graphs which are styled the same with and without the use of `Callout`.

Comment: A am using 13.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)

Comment: Same with me (13.3.1 and  Mac ...). With `Callout` the `Labels` are a little bit different. This even happens when you add `BaseStyle -> Directive[Plain, 14, FontFamily -> "Arial"]`.

Comment: Yes, it seems to ignore the styling when stated. It also happens with `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: same behavior in version 13.3.1 (Linux  x86 (64-bit)). Workarounds: (1) Try `LabelingFunction -> (Callout[#, Above] &)` , and (2) `BarChart[<|10 -> 10|>, ChartLabels -> Callout[Automatic, Above], 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, 20}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "Title", 
 FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]`?

Comment: Thanks. I will have a go with these after work when I have more time. It is looking like this is not expected behaviour and could be classed as a bug. I will make a notebook and report it to Wolfram as a potential bug. I have also found a similar issue with DistributionChart. Here the use of Callout is not needed. Rather, the font and line weightings are lighter compared to all other types of plot I have looked at. It is like it is adopting different default values.